# How to host multiple applications on Yii

Tags: frameworks, yii

I have a large project and want to move to the Yii Framework for PHP.

In the same dir i have 3 index page. **index.mail.php**, **index.home.php**, **index.login.php** and i have rewrite rules like *localhost*/**mail**, *localhost*/**home**, *localhost*/**login**. And these urls also accept their own GET and POST datas.

These tree application of course different. But they are using same library. (different view and models but same public classes)

All i want to do is host these 3 and more application at the same time in 1 Yii thread.

How can i do that? In yii, it seems i can only host 1 application at the same time. (maybe im wrong)

--
I'm asking this by regarding to this post: [Which one to go; Yii or Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467828/which-one-to-go-yii-or-symfony). I decided to use Yii.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `Yii` is correct decision and you should stick with it. You can use those three as `modules`.

`Modules are basically small website applications but they can not work independently.` Best option is Using modules for each thing.

you can have them on single yii application

Answer (score 3):

Yii support "module" which have full functionality of MVC website, it is appropriate in your case.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module